# New version of the program is not working

Tags: linux, bin

I'm working in a program where I have a .cpp file. I've made some changes to the source code in the .cpp file. When I do the make file, everything seems to be running well. However, when I'm trying out the program it seems as though the old version is the one being executed and not the new one. Any thoughts why this is happening?.
I've heard that I need to move the new version of the program to the bin directory; I've done so, yet I haven't been successful.

Comment: What happens if you run the program using an absolute pathname?

Comment: Do you run `make` and a program still works as if an old .cpp file is used? In this case is your Makefile hand-written? If so, you can have forgotten some dependencies such as `logic.o: logic.cpp ...` or `program: logic.o ...`, so `make` does not know that some files need to be updated on .cpp file change. In this case you can try to carefully study Makefile writing or use some Makefile generators such as CMake. Personally me choose the second option because I hope they specify the dependencies better than I can manually do.